# Leaflet, add WFS modifying a working example

Tags: leaflet, wfs-t

I like this example of the boroughs of Amsterdam:

[Boroughs of Amsterdam wfs in leaflet](http://maptime-ams.github.io/Leaflet-D3-workshop/tutorial-leaflet-advanced/3/?fbclid=IwAR0Hu4Jd0FTpfC7-zjBD7AvU-8hafIqyS9Mzlw40XtZgXtqK881LWGUTZ7A)

https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/wijkenbuurten2014/ows?service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=EPSG:4326&typeName=wijkenbuurten2014:cbs_buurten_2014&maxFeatures=1&outputformat=application/json

But how is it possible that I'm trying to change the WFS with my own geoserver services, and it doesn't work? I've enabled geojsonp in the past.
I tried to find and delete  the properties that are not there.

```
        var geojson = L.geoJson(null,
            {
                style: getStyle,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }
        ).addTo(map);

        var url = 'https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/wijkenbuurten2014/ows?';

        // These parameters are identical for all GeoJSON-requests:
        var params = 'service=WFS&version=2.0.0&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=EPSG:4326&';

        // These parameters have to be modified per GeoJSON-request
        // Request the neighbourhood map 2014:
        params += 'typeName=wijkenbuurten2014:cbs_buurten_2014&';

        // Just the attributes: personenautos_per_huishouden en geometrie
        params += 'propertyName=buurtnaam,personenautos_per_huishouden,geom&';

        // Just the neighbourhoods within the municipality of Amsterdam
        params += 'cql_filter=gemeentenaam \= \'Amsterdam\'';

        // Ajax without jQuery ;-)
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', encodeURI(url + params));
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                geojson.addData(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();

        function getStyle(features) {
            var rate = features.properties.personenautos_per_huishouden;
            return {
                    color: '#fff',
                    fillColor: getColour(rate),
                    weight: 0.8,
                    opacity: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 0.9
                }
        }

        function getColour(d) {
            var colour,
            colorScale = chroma
                .scale('YlOrBr')
                .domain([0,1.5]);
            if (d < 0) {
                colour = '#eee'
            } else {
                colour = colorScale(d).hex()
            }
            return colour;
        }
```

--and my unworking code:

```
        var geojson = L.geoJson(null,
            {
                style: getStyle,
                onEachFeature: onEachFeature
            }
        ).addTo(map);

        var url = 'http://vdlibraries.fr/geoserver/france/ows?';

        // These parameters are identical for all GeoJSON-requests:
        var params = 'service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&outputFormat=application/json&srsName=EPSG:4326&';

        // These parameters have to be modified per GeoJSON-request
        // Request the neighbourhood map 2014:
        params += 'typeName=france%3ATM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3';

        // Just the attributes: personenautos_per_huishouden en geometrie
  //      params += 'propertyName=buurtnaam,personenautos_per_huishouden,geom&';

        // Just the neighbourhoods within the municipality of Amsterdam
     //   params += 'cql_filter=gemeentenaam \= \'Amsterdam\'';

        // Ajax without jQuery ;-)
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', encodeURI(url + params));
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                geojson.addData(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
            } else {
                alert('Request failed.  Returned status of ' + xhr.status);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();

        function getStyle(features) {
            var rate = features.properties.iso2;
            return {
                    color: '#fff',
                    fillColor: '#fff',
                    weight: 0.8,
                    opacity: 1,
                    fillOpacity: 0.9
                }
        }
```

[My attempt](http://vdlibraries.fr/test/test3.html)

[World borders  services I wish to add](http://vdlibraries.fr/geoserver/france/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=france%3ATM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson)

http://vdlibraries.fr/geoserver/france/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=france%3ATM_WORLD_BORDERS_SIMPL-0.3&maxFeatures=1&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

Comment: @TomazicM  ok, I just added the relevant services adresses, the rest may not be relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a letter missing or too much, but I found what was the problem, it was :
that it was required to allow WFS services in the Workspace settings, right into Geoserver. It works now.

[image: Geoserver Workspaces]

[image: the working code]